# SQL: converting columns to rows

Tags: sql

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
date ---- x ---- y ---- z
2020----- 2 ---- 4 ---- 8
2018 ---- 3 ---- 3 ---- 2
2019 ---- 1 ---- 6 ---- 0
```

I like to rotate this table meaning that the columns become rows like this:

```
date ---- metric ---- value
2020 ----    x   ----  2
2018 ----    x   ----  3
2019 ----    x   ----  1
2020 ----    y   ----  4
2018 ----    y   ----  3
2019 ----    y   ----  6
2020 ----    z   ----  8
2018 ----    z   ----  2
2019 ----    z   ----  0
```

If it was in python, I could do it using the pivote() or t() function. However, I am not sure how to do it with SQL. Could you please help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A canonical method is `union all`:

```
select date, 'x' as metric, x as value from t union all
select date, 'y' as metric, y as value from t union all
select date, 'z' as metric, z as value from t;
```

Some databases support lateral joins, which simplifies this -- and is a bit faster.